# Programmatically set the UITabBarItem icon for every linked ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Currently we are changing the image shown in the UITabBarItem like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // register additional NIB files
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "WeekDayTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "WeekDayCell")

    tabBarItem.title = "Week".localized
    tabBarItem.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Calendar, textColor: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
}
```

The problem with this is, that you have to click on every tab to load the corresponding images.
I thought I could change the images in the UITabBarViewController if I get the list of all UITabBarItems. But this list is always empty.

Which is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Add it in the App Delegate (if it's for all view) or in the root ViewController for the corresponding views.

Comment: Are you using storyboard and therefore trying to change the default icons and titles of the tabs?

Comment: In addition to @lukesIvi comment, set the target view controller's title, not the tabBarItem title, which is a property that I'm fairly certain doesn't exist for tabBarItem.

Comment: Any luck? @hotpizzabox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative—perhaps a more Swift-y—way to do this is to set the icons from a Dictionary of tabs. We have an enum `TabTitles` for the names of the tabs, and `tabIcons` to look it up.

This way, there's not so much to remember to change if you add a tab or change the order.

```
private enum TabTitles: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Stacks
    case Settings
    case Clusters
    case Services
    case Registries

    private var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

private var tabIcons = [
    TabTitles.Stacks: FontAwesome.Clone,
    TabTitles.Settings: FontAwesome.Gears,
    TabTitles.Clusters: FontAwesome.Cubes,
    TabTitles.Services: FontAwesome.Exchange,
    TabTitles.Registries: FontAwesome.Institution
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let tabBarItems = tabBar.items {
        for item in tabBarItems {
            if let title = item.title,
              tab = TabTitles(rawValue: title),
              glyph = tabIcons[tab] {
                item.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(glyph, textColor: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution :D

Answer (score 4):

I found out, if I add this code to the `viewDidAppear` in the UITabBarController it will work.

```
let tabBarItems = tabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem]

tabBarItems[0].title = "Week".localized
tabBarItems[0].image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Calendar, textColor: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(30, 30))

tabBarItems[1].title = "Settings".localized
tabBarItems[1].image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(FontAwesome.Gears, textColor: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

You can set tabBarItems icons from your first controller 'viewDidLoad' method.

```
   func setupTabBar() {
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].title = "Week"
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-clinic")     
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].title = "Profile"
    tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-phone_not_being_used_filled")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `item.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: glyph, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))` for Swift 3.

Also remember to import FontAwesome_swift